# I want the query to return the id of users who registered 7days from now

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

This query should return the `user_id` of users who have registered 7 days from now,

I know that there is a users table `wp_users`, and in this table, there is a column `user_registered` that holds the date the user registered.

I also know

```
user_registered >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY and user_registered <= now()
```

but I don't know how to combine all these to achieve my result. I would be glad if you could help.. Thanks

```
SELECT user_id  
FROM wpcg_usermeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = 2
```

Comment: "7 days from now" means in the future. I think you mean "less than 7 days ago"

Comment: 7days ago i mean, am sorry

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables.

```
SELECT m.user_id
FROM wpcg_usermeta AS m
JOIN wpcg_users AS u ON u.id = m.user_id
WHERE u.user_registered BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND NOW()
AND m.meta_key = 'user_parent'
AND m.meta_value = 2
```

And unless users can register in the future, there's no need to test if the registration date is less than `NOW()`, so you can just use:

```
WHERE u.user_registered >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

Comment: I really appreciate this but "m" does not have a field called user_id so it triggers error but it has a column called meta_key which has a field called nickname , the value for this nickname correspond with user_nicename column in "u" table

Comment: I got that from the query you showed in the question.

Comment: What's the difference between `wpcg_usermeta` and `wp_usermeta`?

Comment: What is the column that relates different rows in `wpcg_usermeta` that are for the same user?

Comment: okay, let me see if i could ask the question in the right way

 ( SELECT  user_id  FROM wpcg_usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'user_parent' AND meta_value = 1 )

Comment: when i run this query, i get some list of result, i want to check the result in a table called wp_user, if the result has a value that ranges between the value of another column in wp_user,  then i will display the one that is true

Comment: Find a column in `wp_user` and `wpcg_usermeta` that relates the two tables, and join on that.

Comment: Can you post the schemas of `wpcg_usermeta` and `wp_user` in the question?

Comment: The WordPress documentation doesn't mention a table named `wpcg_usermeta`. Where does that come from?

Comment: thats the prefix of my database

Comment: If the `wpcg_usermeta` table doesn't have a column named `user_id`, how can `SELECT user_id FROM wpcg_usermeta` work?

Comment: its wpcg_users table that doesn't have a column named user_id

Comment: I just checked the WP documentation, it's `wp_users.id`.

Comment: @Sulaimonabiola: then why did you tell Barmar that that `wpcg_usermeta` (aliaed as `m` in the query) didn't have a column named `user_id` ? Even as talented and knowledgeable as Barmar is, I don't believe he has the power to summon the database schema definitions or example data.

Comment: i believe its working fine, Thanks so much your code works, i realized the table that connects them and i assigned it

Comment: SELECT COUNT(m.user_id)
FROM wpcg_usermeta AS m
JOIN wpcg_users AS u ON m.user_id = u.ID
WHERE u.user_registered BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) AND NOW()
AND m.meta_key = 'user_parent'
AND m.meta_value = 1